# MongoDB Aggregate Query On Property

Tags: mongodb, grouping, average

I have the following document structure stored in a collection:

```
{
    "name": "Empire State Building",
    "location": {
        "city": "New York",
        "lat": 54.665434,
        "lng": 3.34434
    }
}
```

The collection contains the coordinates of various landmarks in a number of different cities across the world.

What I want to be able to do, is get the average `lat` and `lng` for all cities based on the records within the collection.

So far I am  not having  much luck, I can pull out distinct city  names using the following query:

```
db.pubs.distinct("Location.City").sort()
```

However I am at a loss on where to start with getting the average of the lat and lng properties for all matching values.

If it makes any difference I am using the `mongo shell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$avg` operator is your friend. [`$avg documentation`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)

```
db.pubs.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
                _id: "$location.city", 
                 avgLat: {$avg : "$location.lat"}, 
                 avgLng: {$avg : "$location.lng" }
    }}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try mongo aggregation. Below aggregation may work in your case

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
"$match": {
    "location.city": "New York"
}
},
{
"$group": {
    "_id": 0,
    "LatAvg": {
        "$avg": "$location.lat"
    },
    "LongAvg": {
        "$avg": "$location.lng"
    }
}
})
```